# Avoid typescript errors due to parcel aliases?

Tags: typescript, parceljs, preact

I am starting a webapp using preact with typescript and parcel as a bundler.

I'd like to avoid using preact-specific imports, so (as per the parcel docs) I added this parcel-specific configuration to my package.json:

```
"alias": {
    "react": "preact/compat",
    "react-dom/test-utils": "preact/test-utils",
    "react-dom": "preact/compat",
    "react/jsx-runtime": "preact/jsx-runtime"
},
```

With that configuration, this import works fine when the application is compiled/started with parcel:

```
import * as React from "react";
```

However, the typescript language service and therefore IDEA is highlighting it as an error

```
TS2307: Cannot find module 'react' or its corresponding type declarations
```

which is understandable, of course, because typescript does not know about parcel specific stuff.

[image: ts-error-in-idea]

My current workaround is to also have react installed in devDependencies in addition to preact in dependencies. That just feels wrong. Is there another option?

Comment: do you have `@types/react` in `package.json` file?

Comment: I added both `@types/react-dom` and `@types/react` .
Now I get another error, this time on "ReactDOM" in the import statement instead of the "recat-dom" as before: `TS1192: Module ".../node_module/@types/react-dom/index" has no default export`.

Comment: Can you check `tsconfig.json` file and check if `esModuleInterop` is true?

Comment: In `tsconfig.json` use the `"paths"` option to mirror the aliases: `"paths": { "react": ["preact/compat"],
    "react-dom/test-utils": ["preact/test-utils"],
    "react-dom": ["preact/compat"],
    "react/jsx-runtime": ["preact/jsx-runtime"] }`. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths